# Backstage View in Visual C++ applications

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2013

This is my first app on Visual C++ and I want to make GUI like in Office. So I use MFC. In Visual Studio I created project. Everything is good except the following moment: when I click `File` tab on Ribbon the standard menu appeared, but not the Backstage View, similar to [Office Backstage View](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/word-help/what-and-where-is-backstage-view-HA010370584.aspx). What shall I do for using Backstage View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Former Office version didn't had this full back stage view. 
The current MFC implementation of VS-2010 uses the style introduced with Office 2007. There was no backstage view.

The current (commercial) BCG library or Codejock also supports such a backstage view with there code and wizards.

For a beginner it will be complicated. But it should be possible to Intercept the command, when the user chooses this upper button. So create your own CMFCRibbonApplicationButton implementation. Overwrite CMFCRibbonApplicationButton::OnLButtonDown.

Also you can remove the CMFCRibbonApplicationButton and create your own Category, that does the action. I never tried this, but it should be possible because there is a virtual function CreateApplicationButton in the CMFCRibbonConstructor.

Than you are free to switch the view in the main frame... Keywords to search for the howto, would be "switch view mfc". You will find several code samples.

HTH

Comment: And what about VS-2013? It seems VS-2013 implements Fluent 14.

Comment: I see no difference there. I just used the wizard. Without any own Action you will not have a backstage view like in Office.